# How to exclude urls already scraped while doing scraping using scrapy framework

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am scraping a news website which extracts news data and dumps it to MongoDB.

My spider is defined with the following rule:

```
rules = [Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
                allow=["foo.tv/en/*",
                       "https://fooports.tv/*"]  # only such urls
```

What I currently do that it fetches already scraped urls from database and does not process those urls if it is found in database eg:

```
    urls_visited = get_visited_urls() # Fetches from MongoDB
    if response.url not in urls_visited:
        # do scraping here
```

What I am looking for is there way to make spider to skip those urls which have already been scraped. I want to try to reduce the crawling time by not looking at those urls which have already been processed. I know there is a deny feature in the rule but not sure how can I make use of that in this case.

I have included Downloader Middleware custom class to filter out the requests which has already been scraped :

```
class NewsCrawlerDownloaderMiddleware:
    # Not all methods need to be defined. If a method is not defined,
    # scrapy acts as if the downloader middleware does not modify the
    # passed objects.

    def __init__(self):
        self.urls_visited = get_visited_urls() # from database

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        # This method is used by Scrapy to create your spiders.
        s = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(s.spider_opened, signal=signals.spider_opened)
        return s

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        # Called for each request that goes through the downloader
        # middleware.

        # Must either:
        # - return None: continue processing this request
        # - or return a Response object
        # - or return a Request object
        # - or raise IgnoreRequest: process_exception() methods of
        #   installed downloader middleware will be called
        # Here we check if url has already been scraped,
        # if not process the requests
        if request.url in self.urls_visited:
            logging.info('ignoring url %s', request.url)
            raise IgnoreRequest()
        else:
            return request
```

My middleware order in `settings.py`

```
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'news_crawler.middlewares.NewsCrawlerDownloaderMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
```

however when it tries to crawl first url it gives me the following error:

```
ERROR: Error downloading <GET https://arynews.tv/robots.txt>: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Any ideas how can I properly use my custom downloader middleware to to filter out the urls.

Comment: FYI it’s __scraping__ (and __scrape__, __scraper__, __scraped__) not scrapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a downloader middleware, that will perform filtering of requests based on you database queries. Check out [documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html).

In this case you need to define class with [`process_request(request, spider)`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.DownloaderMiddleware.process_request) method and enable this middleware in your settings (depends how you launch your spider - via cli or within python script).

Alternatively you can define your own duplication filter, take a look at [dupefilters.py](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/dupefilters.py). But this might be a bit more complicated approach, as you need to have some understanding and experience with scrapy.

Comment: I get the error: RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object, when I try to filter my requests in downloader middleware ```process_requests```

Comment: It's interesting, as it fails on `robots.txt`. I'm pretty sure you don't run spider with explicitly passing `arynews.tv/robots.txt`, also I doubt that this link is present somewhere in the page. It's worth mentioning that you have `RobotsTxtMiddleware` in your list of middlewares, which is executed before your own middleware. It downloads robots file according to [source code](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/7e23677b52b659b11471a63f3be9905a0bbaf995/scrapy/downloadermiddlewares/robotstxt.py). Could it be the reason for conflict? Could you try run spider with robots middleware disabled?

Comment: @CyberPunk Also could you check db if it has any links to `*/robots.txt`?

Comment: I checked the db and it doesnot contain any url with ```*/robots.txt```. I will give it a try by removing ```RobotsTxtMiddleware```

Comment: When I remove ```RobotsTxtMiddleware
   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware': None,
```
It just stucks here:`
```2021-05-18 00:05:03 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6061```

Comment: Then I am out of ideas. Are you sure your middleware works as expected? Could it be that it has stuck on `get_visited_urls`, which blocked any other work?